# How to Set Target Directory for Windows Context Menu "Copy To" and "Move To" Options

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, file-transfer, context-menu

It's reasonably well understood that one can add "Copy To" and "Move To" options to the Windows File Explorer context menu by adding the following keys, respectively:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{C2FBB630-2971-11D1-A18C-00C04FD75D13}

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{C2FBB631-2971-11D1-A18C-00C04FD75D13}
```

So far, so good but the target directory in the window that opens is deep in the bowels of one's C:\ drive.  This leaves one having to navigate up 4-6 levels and then back down several levels to get to one's working directory, which is an idiotic design.

In contrast, Nautilus, the Ubuntu file browser, defaults to the selected object's directory, which obviously is far more useful.

The question is, in the Windows case, whether and how the target directory for the "Copy To" and "Move To" options be configured to be either an absolute or relative path.

Any constructive thoughts would be welcome.  A couple of hours on Google turned up nothing on point.

Comment: Just right-button drag it and then choose copy or move.  Or Ctrl-c then Ctrl-p in same folder or another.  What is causing you a problem?

Comment: `In contrast, Nautilus, the Ubuntu file browser, defaults to the selected object's directory` .. you didn't hack Nautilus' config files and it was designed to do the exact thing it does.  Adding random things to your registry because some random website said it would work isn't a good plan.  This hack is a horrible workaround for people who don't understand how to use windows.  The "Open File Dialog" as it is called is no different than opening another explorer window and dragging (as @BlindSpots points out).  [Ctrl]+n will open a fresh copy of the current window to recreate this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Pictures folder. The screen recording/capture program I use saves files to there.

So the solution is to make symbolic link

```
Mklink /d newpath oldpath
```

The /d option makes a directory link.

Now, I have a link called Pictures in the root  of my boot drive, ie `C:\Pictures`.